# AAD Connect provisioning agent configuration doesn't accept global administrator credentials

Tags: azure-active-directory

I've installed the latest version of MS AAD Connect Provisioning Agent (1.1.997.0), however the authentication step fails with the error "Please provide the Azure AD credentials of a global administrator or a hybrid administrator." I've tried both types (a gAdmin account as well as a hybrid identity admin) with no success. Is there a known issue?

I just followed the instructions as documented by MS.

- downloaded and installed the latest version of the agent from AAD Connect cloud sync provisioning blade.
- Once the agent installs the AAD authentication wizard launches but no matter which creds I use (global or hybrid admin), the error persists.

Instructions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/cloud-sync/tutorial-pilot-aadc-aadccp

Comment: I want to add the the "Internet Explorer enhanced security" is disabled for the AD-joined server being used for this installation.

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below error with Non-Admin Account credentials***

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6okX4.png]

**Steps to Create AAD Connect Configuration:**

1)Download the AAD Connect tool [**here**](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=47594) and install.
2)Select Customize -> Choose any sign in method (For testing I selected password hash synchronization) -> Next
3)Make sure to enter **Global admin** credentials to sync to Azure AD.
4)Enter your On-Prem DC Admin credentials to verify the DC access, you will get below screen once you validate both Azure AD Global and DC Admin Credentials.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSgTc.png]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1C9LN.png]

5)Complete next steps and finish the installation.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkb2P.png]

6)Verify Sync after completing the AAD installation.
7)Open Synchronization Service Manager and check sync Status.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XyrqL.png]

8)Also check the status in Azure Portal

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOSEY.png]

To disable `IE Enhanced Security`, you can follow below steps:

***Go to Server Manager -> Local Servers -> IE Enhanced Security Configuration -> Select Off***

[image]